# When Running android app I get ADB error

Tags: android

When i running Android App i got following error..

```
[2010-03-27 02:47:28 - HelloAndroid] Connection with adb was interrupted.
[2010-03-27 02:47:28 - HelloAndroid] 0 attempts have been made to reconnect.
[2010-03-27 02:47:28 - HelloAndroid] You may want to manually restart adb from the Devices view.
```

How can i fix this ?
Thanks 
Atul Yadav

Comment: Upgrade the SDK Tools. That usually happened me on 1.6 emulator. Run: `adb shell` in your console.

Comment: Start eclipse using eclipse.exe -clean

Answer (score 2):

I solve this problem by remove the IPV6 localhost address from my hosts file and by restarting Eclipse.

```
 #::1            localhost
 #fe80::1%lo0    localhost
```

Mac OS x 10.7

adb 1.0.29

Answer (score 1):

Instead of clicking the Run shortcut directly, try this.

Go to Run > Run Configurations

Select your App

Click the tab marked Target(between Android and Common, below Name:)

Check the box under "Select a preferred Android Virtual Device for deployment:" with the correct AVD ie. 2_2_Default_HV...

Then press Run at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone finds this looking for an answer.

If you are running Linux (I'm running Debian but this will work on the Ubuntu too) you may find that ipv6 is bound and that is preventing eclipse and the ddms from connecting to the adb. To check if ipv6 is running, enter this into a terminal/shell:

```
sudo sysctl -a|grep net.ipv6.bindv6only
```

if you are then given a line saying "net.ipv6.bindv6only = 1" then ipv6 bind only is enabled. To disable it enter this in a terminal:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.binv6only=0
```

That will disable it. Now restart eclipse and try again. If that works then it was indeed ipv6 bindings that caused the issue. To permanently disable it edit the file /etc/sysctl.d/bindv6only and change the value from 1 to 0.

Comment: its not working for me .. i have the net.ipv6.bindv6only=0, but still my application is not installing in emulator. please help